# apply a function with two dataframes as input in r

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, sapply

I want to get the total number of `NA` that missmatch between two dataframes. 
I have found the way to get this for two vectors as follows:

```
compareNA <- function(v1,v2) {
  same <- (v1 == v2) | (is.na(v1) & is.na(v2))
  same[is.na(same)] <- FALSE
  n <- 0
  for (i in 1:length(same))
  if (same[i] == "FALSE"){
    n <- n+1
  }
  return(n)
}
```

Lets say I have vector `a`and `b`when comparing them I got as a result 2

```
 a <- c(1,2,NA, 4,5,6,NA,8)
 b <- c(NA,2,NA, 4,NA,6,NA,8)
 h <- compareNA(a,b)
 h
[1] 2
```

My question is: how to apply this function for dataframes instead of vectors?

Having as an example this datafames:

```
a2 <- c(1,2,NA,NA,NA,6,NA,8)
b2 <- c(1,NA,NA,4,NA,6,NA,NA)

df1 <- data.frame(a,b)
df2 <- data.frame(a2,b2)
```

what i expect as a result is 5, since this are the total number of `NA`s that appear in df2 that are not in df1. Any suggestion how to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A third way (assuming dimensions of df1 & df2 are same):

```
sum(sapply(1:ncol(df1), function(x) compareNA(df1[,x], df2[,x])))
# 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a second thought.

```
xy1 <- data.frame(a = c(NA, 2, 3), b = rnorm(3))
xy2 <- data.frame(a = c(NA, 2, 4), b = rnorm(3))

com <- intersect(colnames(xy1), colnames(xy2))

sum(xy1[, com] == xy2[, com], na.rm = TRUE)
```

If you don't want to worry about column names (but you should), you can make sure the columns align perfectly. In that case, `intersect` step is redundant.

```
sum(xy1 == xy2, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to force both dataframes to have the same column names and compare column by column when those have the same name. You can then simply use a loop over columns and increment a running total by applying your function.

```
compareNA.df <- function(df1, df2) {

   total <- 0
   common_columns <- intersect(colnames(df1), colnames(df2))

   for (col in common_columns) {

      total <- total + compareNA(df1[[col]], df2[[col]])

   }
   return(total)
}

colnames(df2) <- c("a", "b")

compareNA.df(df1, df2)
```

Comment: But what if I have dataframes that do not have the same colnames, then I have to change the names of columns?

Comment: @mina that, or omit `intersect` and make sure the columns align perfectly.

Comment: At one point, you'll need some rule to match columns together, this can be by name (what I used here) and using intersect. Another way would be to add a `by` argument like the `merge` function or like the `join` functions of `dplyr`. You could also match them by position as Roman stated above.